# My pc is disconnecting automatic from wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless

Laptop : HP pavilion g6
Router : Huawei HG538
OS : Xubuntu

Problem is my pc automatically disconnect from wi-fi in 1 hour after boot.

Comment: Please add output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" command to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by replacing Network Manager with Wicd:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wicd
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo service wicd restart
```

Comment: Please mark as solved.

Comment: You have to wait for 48 hours after you posted the question before you can mark your own answer as solved, by the way.