# Ubuntu 15.04 - Internet gets constantly interrupted since one week ago

Tags: internet, 15.04

Since one week ago, my internet connection suffers constantly interruptions. It works, it goes away, it works, it goes away.

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and until now it had everything worked fine. Any idea? What should I do?

Other devices connected to the wifi work fine

Comment: yes. i too face the same prob. losing my internet connectivity. have to restart to get the connectivity. then i lose it again after a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

This question seems to be similar: [My pc is disconnecting automatic from wi-fi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624822/my-pc-is-disconnecting-automatic-from-wi-fi) and I have tried the solution offered:

Replace Network Manager with Wicd:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wicd
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager network-manager-gnome
sudo service wicd restart
```

And reboot your machine.

This solved the problem for me. Since then I've tried changing back to network-manager once, but then the connection problems returned immediately. Wicd has worked flawless ever since.

There was just one more problem to tackle. I use a Cisco VPN connection quite a lot and Wicd doesn't support that out of the box. So, I needed a vpnc client. Wicd is not as easy as Network-manager in that respect, but the following websites helped me getting that to work as well:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vpnc-gui/

Hope this will help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Mobile Broadband from the network menu.
That did the trick for me.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: After disabling mobile broadband, I had no connection problems (wifi or wired) for 2 days, but then they they returned. Not a solution after all.