# My Laptop automatically disconnects from wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, lenovo, broadcom

My laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04. It automatically disconnects from wifi after 4-5 minutes. After that it refuses to reconnect. I then turn off and on the wifi of the laptop from the hardware key. After several tries it connects somehow. I've already read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624822/my-pc-is-disconnecting-automatic-from-wi-fi)and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530262/computer-automatically-disconnects-from-wifi-i-have-to-restart-to-get-back-onli) but couldn't solve the problem.

Here is the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0621]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
```

(I don't know what the above command does. I've read in those questions that you ask for its output.) Help me out if you know what is the issue?

Comment: This command shows  your wireless adapter model and the driver in use.

Comment: And what is your laptop model?

Comment: @Pilot6: Ok thanks! I believe I should have focused more in my shell scripting class.  :-)

Comment: @Pilot6: It is Lenovo Z50-70 370339

Comment: Try to run `sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop` and test it again. But do not reboot.

Comment: @Pilot6: done! Now waiting for it to disconnect.

Comment: If it does not, I will write a solution to make it permanent.

Comment: @Pilot6, Sure but let me wait for 20-30 minutes more.. Or should I try disconnecting and reconnecting it? If it connects in first attempt, probably  it would be solved?

Comment: Just run it for a while.

Comment: @Pilot6: run what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25788/discussion-between-pilot6-and-arby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have problems with `ideapad_laptop` module.

This module is responsible for platform specific features one of them is handling wireless blocking and unblocking.

Lately some bugs have been reported for some Lenovo laptops. Some of them have been fixed, some are not even reported.

First of all I suggest upgrading kernel to 3.19. It will install a newer `ideapad_laptop`. There is a chance that this issue is fixed there.

To upgrade the kernel run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.

Then test your wireless network for a while.

If the problem persists, you can permanently disable `ideapad_laptop` module by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad_laptop.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

This must solve the problem.

This setting can be always reverted by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad_laptop.conf
```

If upgrading kernel does not solve the problem I suggest reporting the bug to launchpad. You will need to remove the blacklist and run in terminal

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

and follow the directions.

This will help to solve this problem for everyone. You can post link to the bug here.